# Why secure methods in Spring Security and not just URLs?

Tags: methods, spring-security

- Is it not enough to secure URLs?
- Is there a way a user could call an URL without the needed credentials and this is the reason to secure methods?
- Can you provide a real example why securing methods is necessary and not just URLs?

Comment: what do you mean by "secured method"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually enough to secure only URLs in simple cases. Think about method level security  as an addition to URL level security. For example a simple check that a user has a particular role to access some URL in your app can be achieved with the aid of URL level security.

However, there are cases you need more fine-grained security. If you want to allow to access the given product (id=5) only to its creator, you do not get by with URL level security only. But you can achieve this with method level security.

Consider this URL.

```
https://myapp.com/products/5
```

You can check that a user accessing this URL has role REQUIRED_ROLE.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/products/**" access="hasRole('REQUIRED_ROLE')" />
```

If you need to ensure that the user is also the product creator, you need something like this:

```
...

@PreAuthorize("#product.creator == authentication.name")
public void doSomething(Product product);

...
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Two doubts:                                                      - #product.creator: creator is a property of product and has to be in the database                                                                                - What would be the default behaviour if somebody calls a method and has no permission (return a access denied page? throw an exception?)                                                                                          Thanks

Comment: It was just an example but basically yes, creator is a product's property. If a user does not have the required permission, `AccessDeniedException` will be thrown and the way it is handled depends on your configuration.

Comment: Yes, but where is it configured? For urls I know you can define a custom denied page

Comment: First you have to implement `AccessDeniedHandler` and then assign it to `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. You can achieve this with the aid of Spring Security namespace elements. However, since this is quite complex topic and completely different question, I would suggest you to look at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#overall-architecture). Anyway, if your original question has been answered, mark the answer as accepted so that the others can benefit.