# Security config when using @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My security config class (which inherits from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) has a method like the following.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/restaurant/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
        .formLogin();
}
```

However I'd rather use `@PreAuthorize` on my controllers instead. If I remove the method everything requires auth. What should my method look like so everything is available and access is only determined by PreAuthorize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been already stated, it is not very common to use method level security to secure controller methods but rather to secure methods with business logic. And even if you need to perform authorization based on request attributes, it should be possible to achieve this with URL based security and web security expressions.

> Available expressions are defined by `WebSecurityExpressionRoot` class, an instance of which is used as the expression root object when evaluation web-access expressions. This object also directly exposed the `HttpServletRequest` object under the name `request` so you can invoke the request directly in an expression.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127755/why-to-secure-methods-in-spring-security-and-not-just-urls/26137528#26137528) you can find more details on when to use URL based security and when method level security.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather uncommon to use @PreAuthorize on controller methods, but there may me use cases, if the decision depends on request parameters ...

If you do not want to do any authorization at the request level, you can simply have :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin();
}
```

You only declare a form login, and no request security. But do not forget that request security uses less resources than method security.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`, try `.access("permitAll")`. Note that for request mappings that doesn't have a `@PreAuthorize`, everyone will be given access.